# crear diccionario desde un registro de un dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

Por favor me podrian ayudar, es que tengo un dataframe que tiene 3 columnas,  el caso es que como pueden ver en la imagen, en la columna "Etiqueta" hay registros de unos datos que parecen estar en un formato estilo json , necesito sacar de alli esa info y convertirlo a un diccionario para poder usar las Keys y los Values, alguien conoce alguna manera de poder hacerlo?  Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero intenté pasar solo esa columna a otro dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego convertí el dataframe a un diccionario lo cual generó una sola key llamada etiqueta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego creé otro diccionario a partir de esa key para tenerlo mas limpio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después procedí  a guardar en una lista esos values con la funcion extend,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego con json.loads() logré convertir un elemento de la lista a diccionario, pero ahora no se como hacer para que por medio de un for recorra toda la lista y vaya agreganda los elementos al diccionario, lo traté de hacer asi pero asi solo me carga el ultimo elemento, alguien sabe como agregar elementos a un diccionario a traves de un ciclo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El módulo `json` te ayudará

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega el código que tienes donde has intentado extraer la información y un ejemplo de lo que viene en una entrada de esa columna

Comment: @HeytalePazguato listo ya edité la pregunta con mas info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías obtener directamente el diccionario de tu dataframe sin hacer tantos pasos utilizando `json`

```
import json
```

Para poder obtener directamente un arreglo de diccionarios puedes hacer lo siguiente (Crear un arreglo `data` con todos los diccionarios de tu columna `Etiqueta`)

```
data = df['Etiqueta'].apply(json.loads).array
```

Y para poder acceder a cada elemento lo harías de la siguiente forma

```
data[0]['URL']
```

Donde `0` es el índice de tu arreglo `data` y `URL` la etiqueta que quieres  acceder

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió esta info!.